# Submenu opens to right, but is not visible until scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm making a wordpress site with a categories menu. The problem is that the submenus aren't behaving the way I would like to. Here are some screenshots This are the main menu items.
[image]
here you can see a sub menu item after scrolling to the right
[image]
Is there any way to fix this? I've looked at some menus online and tried adding the CSS codes, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: answering to your question: yes, it's possible to do. but without any code provided it'll be a liitle hard to provide right way for fixing it

Comment: I'm not sure what code to give to you, because it's in wordpress. Should I just inspect and then copy the code from the menu/submenu and css?

Comment: yes, add code from inspect: html code of that part( all menu ) and css related to them